# Bundle Update could not find dependencies while upgrading Rails app from 4.0 to 5.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to upgrade my existing Rails 4.2 application to Rails 5.0. Have changed the Rails gem to 5.0.2 in Gemfile as below.

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem "rake",          "~> 0.9.2"
#gem "rails",         "~> 4.2.7.1"
gem 'rails',         "~> 5.0.1"
gem "mysql2"
gem "mime-types",    "~> 1.16", require: "mime/types"
gem "rubyzip",       "~> 1.1.0"
gem "nokogiri",      "1.6.8".
gem "apn_on_rails",  "0.4.1",   git:"https://bitbucket.orgsheridangroupapn_on_rails.git"
gem "gdata_19",      "~>1.1.5"
gem "gcm_on_rails",  "0.2.1", git: "https://bitbucket.org/sheridangroup/gcm_on_rails"
gem "open4",         "1.0.1"
gem "rmagick",       "2.13.2", require: "RMagick"
gem 'aws-sdk-v1' #aws-sdk v1 is used for url signing, as v2 has a one-week expiration limit
gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
gem "libxml-ruby",   "~> 2.7.0", require: "libxml"
gem "bitly",         "0.10.0"
gem "uuid",          "~> 2.3.7"
gem "htmlentities",  "4.3.4"
gem "paper_trail",   "~> 6.0.2"
gem "mechanize"
gem "rbtree", "0.4.2"
gem "resque"
gem "yajl-ruby" # For resque
gem "json", "~> 1.8.3"
gem "minitest"
gem "will_paginate"
gem "configatron", "~> 2.13.0"
gem "american_date", "~> 1.1.0"
gem "builder"
gem "coderay"
gem "json-schema"
gem "rspec"
gem "jquery-rails", "~> 4.2.2"
gem "jquery-ui-rails"
gem 'jquery-timepicker-addon-rails'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'
gem "net-ftp-list"
gem 'recursive-open-struct'
gem 'slim'
gem 'paranoia'
gem 'typhoeus'
gem 'bundler', '1.12.5'
gem "paperclip", "~> 4.3.7"

group :test do
 #gem 'spork-rails'
 gem 'capybara'
 gem 'poltergeist'
 gem 'simplecov', require: false
 gem 'simplecov-rcov', require: false
 gem 'timecop'
 gem 'test-unit'
end

# Used for NewRelic monitoring in Staging env only
group :staging, :production do
 gem "newrelic_rpm"
 gem "ey_config"
end

group :test, :development do
 gem "rspec-rails", require: false
 gem "listen", ">= 0.5.1", require: false
 gem "machinist", "~> 2.0", require: false
 gem "database_cleaner", "~> 0.9.1", require: false
 gem 'pry-byebug'
end

group :development do
  # <browser-debugging-tools>
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
  gem "meta_request"
  # </browser-debugging-tools>

gem 'quiet_assets' # prevent assets pipeline logging
  gem 'rubocop', '0.35.0'
end

group :assets do
 gem "sass-rails"
 gem "coffee-rails"
 gem "uglifier", "2.7.2"
end
```

Tried running `bundle update` , but got the following error in the console.

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rack":
In Gemfile:
rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
  actioncable (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
    actionpack (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
      rack (~> 2.0)

better_errors was resolved to 2.1.1, which depends on
  rack (>= 0.9.0)

capybara was resolved to 2.12.1, which depends on
  rack (>= 1.0.0)

rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
  actioncable (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
    actionpack (= 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
      rack-test (~> 0.6.3) was resolved to 0.6.3, which depends on
        rack (>= 1.0)

resque was resolved to 1.27.2, which depends on
  sinatra (>= 0.9.2) was resolved to 1.1.0, which depends on
    rack (~> 1.1)

sass-rails was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
  sprockets (< 4.0, >= 2.8) was resolved to 3.7.1, which depends on
    rack (< 3, > 1)
 Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "rails":
 In Gemfile:
rails (~> 5.0.1)

quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.0, which depends on
  rails (~> 3.1)
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
In Gemfile:
coffee-rails was resolved to 4.2.1, which depends on
  railties (< 5.2.x, >= 4.0.0)

jquery-rails (~> 4.2.2) was resolved to 4.2.2, which depends on
  railties (>= 4.2.0)

jquery-timepicker-addon-rails was resolved to 1.4.1, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.1)

quiet_assets was resolved to 1.0.1, which depends on
  railties (~> 3.1)

rails (~> 5.0.1) was resolved to 5.0.1, which depends on
  railties (= 5.0.1)
```

I want to move on in upgrading to Rails 5.0. Can I get a direction to fix all the errors.

```
rspec-rails was resolved to 3.5.2, which depends on
  railties (>= 3.0)

sass-rails was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
  railties (< 6, >= 4.0.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete your Gemfile.lock file and try updating once again.